# angularJS controller script

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to create a page with angularJs.
I have a little question(probably not so clever, but it really gives me a big headache)
I'm using a controller,

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ['app.directives'])
.controller('controle3',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
        $http.get('views/location.html').success(function(data){
            $scope=data;
        });
    }])
```

and this is in my app

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute' , 'app.controllers'])
    .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
          $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/post.html',
        controller:'PostController'

}).when('/location/', {
    templateUrl:'views/location.html',
    controller:'controle3'
```

My question is  how can i run any javascript that is inside location.html, with this controller, when i access the page? Is this possible?

Comment: you have a typo in your routing, the `controller:controle3` does not correspond to your actual controller, which is `controe3`

Comment: I fixed that, but still not working,

Comment: You mean you have some inline javascript in view/location.html?

Comment: Yes I have inline javascript